# Serialization with KStream groupBy operation

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am trying to perform a count operation on a KStream and running into some difficulty in understanding how serialization is working here. I have a stream that is pushing people information e.g. name, age. After consuming this stream, i am trying to create a KTable with a count of people's age.

**Input:**
    {"name" : "abc","age" : "15"}

**Output:**
    30, 10
    20, 4
    10, 8
    35, 22
    ...

**Properties**

```
props.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "person_processor");
props.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
```

**Processor**

```
KStream<Object, Person> people = builder.stream("people");
people.print(Printed.<Object, Person>toSysOut().withLabel("consumer-1"));
```

**Output**
    [consumer-1]: null, [B@7e37bab6

**Question-1**
I understand that data in the topic is in bytes. I am not setting any Serdes for Key or Value to start with. Is KStream converting the input from bytes to Person and printing the address of Person here?

**Question-2**
When I add the below value Serdes, I get a more meaningful output. Is the byte information here getting converted to String and then to Person? Why is the value now printed correctly?

```
props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass());

[consumer-1]: null, {"name" : "abc","age" : "15"}
```

**Question-3**
Now, when performing the count on the age, I get a runtime error on converting a String to Person. If groupBy is setting the age as the Key and the count as Long, why is the String to Person conversion happening?

```
KTable<Integer, Long> integerLongKTable = people.groupBy((key, value) -> value.getAge())
    .count();

Exception in thread "person_processor-9ff96b38-4beb-4594-b2fe-ae191bf6b9ff-StreamThread-1" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to com.example.kafkastreams.KafkaStreamsApplication$Person
at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.KStreamImpl$1.apply(KStreamImpl.java:152)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.KStreamImpl$1.apply(KStreamImpl.java:149)
```

**Edit-1**

After reading through the response from @Matthias J. Sax I created a PersonSerde using the Serializer and DeSerializer from this locatio, I get this SerializationException...

https://github.com/apache/kafka/tree/1.0/streams/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/streams/examples/pageview

```
static class Person {

    String name;
    String age;

    public Person(String name, String age) {

      this.name = name;
      this.age = age;
    }

    void setName(String name) {

      this.name = name;
    }

    String getName() {

      return name;
    }

    void setAge(String age) {

      this.age = age;
    }

    String getAge() {

      return age;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {

      return "Person {name:" + this.getName() + ",age:" + this.getAge() + "}";
    }
  }

public class PersonSerde implements Serde {

  @Override
  public void configure(Map map, boolean b) {

  }

  @Override
  public void close() {

  }

  @Override
  public Serializer serializer() {

    Map<String, Object> serdeProps = new HashMap<>();

    final Serializer<Person> personSerializer = new JsonPOJOSerializer<>();
    serdeProps.put("JsonPOJOClass", Person.class);
    personSerializer.configure(serdeProps, false);

    return personSerializer;
  }

  @Override
  public Deserializer deserializer() {

    Map<String, Object> serdeProps = new HashMap<>();

    final Deserializer<Person> personDeserializer = new JsonPOJODeserializer<>();
    serdeProps.put("JsonPOJOClass", Person.class);
    personDeserializer.configure(serdeProps, false);

    return personDeserializer;
  }
}

props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass());
props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, personSerde.getClass());

KTable<String, Long> count = people.selectKey((key, value) -> value.getAge()).groupByKey(Serialized.with(Serdes.String(), personSerde))
      .count();
```

**Error**

```
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error serializing JSON message
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class com.example.kafkastreams.KafkaStreamsApplication$Person and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException.from(InvalidDefinitionException.java:77)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider.reportBadDefinition(SerializerProvider.java:1191)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DatabindContext.reportBadDefinition(DatabindContext.java:313)
```

**Edit 5**

So it appears that when I mapValues to a String, then count works correctly. But when I use it on a custom Object, it fails

```
KStream<String, Person> people = builder.stream("person-topic", Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), personSerde));
people.print(Printed.<String, Person>toSysOut().withLabel("person-source"));

KStream<String, Person> agePersonKStream = people.selectKey((key, value) -> value.getAge());
agePersonKStream.print(Printed.<String, Person>toSysOut().withLabel("age-person"));

KStream<String, String> stringStringKStream = agePersonKStream.mapValues((person -> person.name));
stringStringKStream.print(Printed.<String, String>toSysOut().withLabel("age-name"));

KTable<String, Long> stringLongKTable = stringStringKStream.groupByKey(Serialized.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.String())).count();
stringLongKTable.toStream().print(Printed.<String, Long>toSysOut().withLabel("age-count"));
```

Without the 3 step to mapValues to name, step 4 fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Question-1 I understand that data in the topic is in bytes. I am not setting any Serdes for Key or Value to start with. Is KStream converting the input from bytes to Person and printing the address of Person here?

If you don't specify any `Serde` in `StreamsConfig` or in `builder.stream(..., Consumers.with(/*serdes*/))` the bytes won't be converted into a `Person` object but the object will be of type `byte[]`. Thus, `print()` will call `byte[].toString()` that results in the cryptic output (`[B@7e37bab6`) you see.

> Question-2 When I add the below value Serdes, I get a more meaningful output. Is the byte information here getting converted to String and then to Person? Why is the value now printed correctly?

As you specify `Serde.String()` in `StreamsConfig` the bytes are converted to `String` type. It seems, that `StringSerde` is able to deserialize the bytes in a meaningful way -- but this seems to be a coincidence that it works at all. It seems that your data is actually serialized in JSON, what would explain why `StringSerde()` can convert the bytes into a `String`.

> Question-3 Now, when performing the count on the age, I get a runtime error on converting a String to Person. If groupBy is setting the age as the Key and the count as Long, why is the String to Person conversion happening?

That is expected. Because the bytes are converted into a `String` object (as you specified `Serdes.String()`), the cast cannot be performed.

**Final remarks:**

You don't get a class cast exception if you only use `print()`, because for this case, no cast operation is performed. Java only inserts a cast operation if required.

For `groupBy()` you use `value.getAge()` and thus Java inserts a cast here (it knows that the expected type is `Person`, because it's specified via `KStream<Object, Person> people = ...`. For `print()` only `toString()` is called that is define on `Object` and thus no cast is required.

Generics in Java a type hints for the compiler and replaced with `Object` (or casted if required during compile time). Thus, for `print()` a `Object` variable can point to an `byte[]` without problem and `toString()` is called successfully. For `groupBy()` case the compiler cast `Object` to `Person` to be able to call `getAge()` -- however, this fails, because the actually type is `String`.

To get your code working, you need to create a `PersonSerde extend Serde<Person>` class and specify it as value serde.

Comment: Thank you for taking time to respond and help clearing my doubts.

Comment: I tried the option to create a PersonSerde but running into some DeSerialization errors. Any Thoughts?

Comment: Not sure of the top of my head how `jackson` works, but it seems you don't wire up the serializer correctly.

Comment: Updated the post. Mapping Values to String works and I get the count; but not with Custom Object. It appears that count operation requires Serializer to be set but I am not sure why or how.

Comment: As I said, the stack trace indicates that you don't setup your `JsonPOJOSerializer` correctly. This seems to be an independent issue and is not related to Kafka Streams. Checkout the examples in this repos that also contains some examples using Json: https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-streams-examples (SO is not a code debugging service.)

Comment: Got it. It was an issue with the Person object not exposing public accessors (I was using default). Thanks for the help.